# How to output just the Name and Status in drush listing modules

Tags: drush

Running `drush pm-list` gives the modules and theme list through some fields. By default, it gives me the Package, Name, Status and Version.
I am trying to make a shell script that outputs only module and status to be consumed by other scrips, and things will be much easier if the `drush pm-list` shows only Name and Status.

Is there a way to prints only the information about the Name and Status from the `drush pm-list` and omits the Package and Version information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Drush 8 or Drush 9:

```
drush pm-list --fields=Name,Status
```

If you want to consume the output from another script, you might also want to consider:

```
drush pm-list --format=json
```

In that instance, all fields will appear in the output; however, since the output will be in json, it is easy to parse and then use only the fields of interest.